# Boot into windows using grub1.99-21ubuntu3.14

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had a working grub menu list, till I activated express ssd on my ultrabook with both windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04

Now i get a screen showing the minimal CLI mode which Im clueless about.

Did try using chainloader but it returns with invalid efi path.

On pressing tab with chainloader(hd0,
(Hd0 contains windows, hd1 ubuntu, I do not have a recovery disk)
It shows hd0,gpt2 & hd0,gpt6 with filesystem fat and the rest are not a known filesystem.

Please help.

EDIT : On booting a live usb, it still opens up the grub CLI than booting the usb, cannot access the usb boot.

Comment: try boot-repair using ubuntu live usb or cd https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Is there a way I can boot into windows via grub? I would like to learn and drivemap is not a recognized command for the grub line.

Comment: First make a repair and then you will see all os on your disk

Comment: Cant even boot pendrive at the moment. Stuck at the black grub screen

Comment: Thats what I have been trying. Still boots onto the grub screen

Comment: have you put off secured boot and fast boot?

Comment: I had enabled fast boot, via samsung settings, I do not see any such option in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

There are two relatively easy solutions to this problem, although I can't guarantee that either will work:

- Download the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Prepare a medium from the image and boot to it. You should see a rEFInd screen that lets you boot both Windows and Ubuntu. If both options work, boot to Ubuntu and install the Debian-package version of rEFInd. It should then take over as your primary boot program.
- Boot an emergency system *in EFI mode* and run the [Boot Repair program.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) The trickiest part of this is booting in EFI mode, since the details of doing this vary from one computer to another. You must normally use the key (usually a function key, but sometimes Esc or something else) that brings up your boot manager options, and select the option for your boot medium that includes the string "EFI" or "UEFI".

If neither suggestion works, post back with the URL that Boot Repair provides; that will give us more detailed technical information.